# Is it possible to connect to multiple TFS server from Visual Studio 2010 Team Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I want to connect to multiple TFS server from Visual Studio 2010 team explorer. Say I have connect to TFSServer01 and selected  projects P1 and P2. I would also like to connect to another server TFSServer02 and select a project P3. But doing this in team explorer is not possible. It forcibly closes the first connection.
This is the scenario I have. We will have a existing server with TFS 2005 that has our current code. I want to create a new server to install TFS 2010 for new code. But I cannot use the two servers to connect simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the tools (command line and GUI) you work in one workspace at a time. And a workspace cannot span servers (or, in 2010 terms, project groups).

Have you considered upgrading the 2005 TFS to 2010 and continuing to use a single server for both old and new code?

(VS and the tools will handle switching workspaces and servers without problems—including when require for opening a new solution.)

Comment: I have confirmed that this is indeed the case. It is bit unfortunate though. I would love to have connections to multiple TFS servers at once (say company, codeplex and a provate one running in my PC)